# Can I search for factors of $\ (11!)!+11!+1\ $ efficiently?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, prime-factorization

> Is the number $$(11!)!+11!+1$$ a prime number ?

I do not expect that a probable-prime-test is feasible, but if someone actually wants to let it run, this would of course be very nice. The main hope is to find a factor to show that the number is not prime. If we do not find a factor, it will be difficult to check the number for primality. I highly expect a probable-prime-test to reveal that the number is composite.  "Composite" would be a surely correct result. Only if the result would be "probable prime", there would remain slight doubts, but I would be confident with such a test anyway.

Motivation : $(n!)!+n!+1$ can only be prime if $\ n!+1\ $ is prime. This is because a non-trivial factor of $\ n!+1\ $ would also divide $\ (n!)!+n!+1\ $. The cases $\ n=2,3\ $ are easy , but the case $\ n=11\ $ is the first non-trivial case. We only know that there is no factor upto $\ p=11!+1\ $

What I want to know : Can we calculate $$(11!)!\mod \ p$$ for $\ p\ $ having $\ 8-12\ $ digits with a trick ? I ask because pari/gp takes relatively long to calculate this residue directly. So, I am looking for an acceleration of this trial division.

Comment: Damn Peter, back at it again with the large prime numbers 

Comment: By the way, this number is so huge that it would be a record prime.

Comment: There is probably no better way to calculate a factorial mod $p$, as it would turn Wilson's theorem into a prime testing algorithm. But $11!$ is only about $4e7$, so a proper implementation in e.g. C should be fast enough for single query (in less than a second). It's a different story if you want to test for ~$1e6$ primes, though.

Comment: @WhatsUp I do not expect such an algorithm for factorials of $\ 100\ $ digit-numbers. I just want to calcualte a "medium" factorial modulo a "small" prime. The next case $(n=27)$ will probably be already hopeless.

Comment: By the way, from my intuition, it's highly unlikely that this number is prime. But this number is too large to be stored in any memory, so it's hard even to run some simple prime testing, e.g. checking whether the Jacobi symbol equals $(p-1)/2$-th power.

Comment: @WhatsUp You are right with both statements. Therefore, my goal is to find a factor to prove the number composite.

Comment: I'd say your chance is very low with this "test divide" approach, at least without any heuristic on the form of a possible divisor.

Comment: @WhatsUp Unfortunately, there seems to be no useful restriction of the possible prime factors. It could apparently be any prime exceeding $\ 11!+1\ $, Methods like pollard-rho or the p-1-method are probably very slow for such huge numbers.

Comment: Why not ask on MathOverflow?

Comment: `gettime();my(d=Mod(1,c=randomprime(10^14)));parforprime(x=1,11!,sum(y=1,logint(11!,x),floor(logint(11!,x)/y)),j,d*=Mod(x,c)^j);print(d";"gettime())
Mod(23476542536496, 90155091544403);19460`

Comment: found my logic error  should be floor(11!/(x^y)) in the sum ...

Comment: Peter your number has 286,078,171 decimal digits. Too large for a primality test in the next decade I guess.

Comment: if $p$ is 3 or 5 mod 8  then 2 is a generator of the ring mod $p$ I believe so now to figure the exponents on 2.

Comment: https://forthright48.com/prime-factorization-of-factorial/ but in mod.

Comment: Title asks for efficient factorization, but content then asks if $(11!)!+11!+1$ is a prime, so what is the question? It is possible to prove a number is not a prime without finding its factors.

Comment: @Sil This has a point. Since I do not think that we can apply even a probable-prime test (which would with high probability show that the number is composite), the only chance is to find a factor. You are right, that we cannot prove a number composite , if we neither find a factor nor have a probable-prime-test. Do you suggest an edit of the question considering this aspect ?

Comment: @Sil What I hope that there is a relatively small factor we are able to find. If we do not, we probably won't ever know whether this number is prime.

Comment: Well I would just make the question consistent, I think there is nothing wrong when you ask about primality and factorization at once, but then it should be stated in one part of the post (currently there are 2 questions asked in different parts of the post). With the prime checking itself, I think it may still be possible, someone could devise an algorithm that somehow needs $O(n)$ steps to check primality (similar to checking if $2^n-1$ is prime in $O(n)$ steps), but I doubt so :)

Comment: @Sil OK, I will do it. By the way, a probable-prime-test would be as efficient as the Lucas-Lehmer-test for $2^n-1$ , although it would not be a proof for primality. But this would still take a lot time , but of course is feasible in principle.

Comment: @Peter $p=11!+1=39916801$, you can search this number in the box here: http://compoasso.free.fr/primelistweb/page/prime/liste_online_en.php and find it is there. So $p$ is really a prime, but I can't see if $(11!)!+11!+1=(p-1)!+p$ is a prime. I can only see that all of its prime factors will be bigger than $p$.

Comment: Another statement derived from Wilson's theorem is that $$(n-2)!\equiv 1\pmod n$$ if $n$ is prime. So $11!-1$ is not prime, as it is divisible by $13$. This probably doesn't help, but I mean, it's better with than without.

Comment: If this number turns out to be a prime, you can surely claim the (_still unclaimed_) [**prime hunting awards**](https://www.eff.org/awards/coop)! The number has about $286$ million digits.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I let $p_1=1+11!$ for convenience. By Wilson's theorem if there's a prime $p$ that divides $1+11!+(11!)! = p_1 + (p_1-1)!$ then

$$(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod p$$

And also

$$(p_1-1)!\equiv -p_1$$

So

$$(p-1)(p-2)...p_1\cdot(p_1-1)!\equiv -1$$

$$(p-1)(p-2)...p_1\cdot p_1\equiv 1$$

This way I was able to check all the primes from $p_1$ to 74000000 in 12 hours. This gives a 3.4% chance of finding a factor according to big prime country's heuristic. The algorithm has bad asymptotic complexity because to check a prime $p$ you need to perform $p-11!$ modular multiplications so there's not much hope of completing the calculation.

Note that I haven't used that $p_1$ is prime, so maybe that can still help somehow. Here's the algorithm in c++:

```
// compile with g++ main.cpp -o main -lpthread -O3

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <boost/process.hpp>

#include <thread>

namespace bp = boost::process;

const constexpr unsigned int p1 = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 * 10 * 11 + 1; // 11!+1
const constexpr unsigned int max = 100'000'000;                                    // maximum to trial divide
std::vector<unsigned int> primes;
unsigned int progress = 40;

void trial_division(unsigned int n) { // check the primes congruent to 2n+1 mod 16
    for(auto p : primes) {
        if(p % 16 != (2 * n + 1)) continue;
        uint64_t prod = 1;
        for(uint64_t i = p - 1; i >= p1; --i) {
            prod = (prod * i) % p;
        }
        if((prod * p1) % p == 1) {
            std::cout << p << "\n"; 
        }
        if(n == 0 && p > progress * 1'000'000) {
            std::cout << progress * 1'000'000 << "\n";
            ++progress;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    bp::ipstream is;
    bp::child primegen("./primes", std::to_string(p1), std::to_string(max), bp::std_out > is);
    // this is https://cr.yp.to/primegen.html
    // the size of these primes don't really justify using such a specialized tool, I'm just lazy

    std::string line;   
    while (primegen.running() && std::getline(is, line) && !line.empty()) {
        primes.push_back(std::stoi(line));
    } // building the primes vector

    // start 8 threads, one for each core for on my computer, each checking one residue class mod 16
    // By Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions they should progress at the same speed
    // the 16n+1 thread owns the progress counter
    std::thread t0(trial_division, 0);
    std::thread t1(trial_division, 1);
    std::thread t2(trial_division, 2);
    std::thread t3(trial_division, 3);
    std::thread t4(trial_division, 4);
    std::thread t5(trial_division, 5);
    std::thread t6(trial_division, 6);
    std::thread t7(trial_division, 7);

    t0.join();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    t5.join();
    t6.join();
    t7.join();
}
```

I only need to multiply integers of the order of $11!$ so standard 64 bit ints suffice.

**EDIT:** Divisor found! $1590429889$

So first of all, the Wilson's theorem trick slows down instead of speeding up after $2p_1$. Secondly, the trial division function is nearly infinitely parallelizable, which means that it's prone to being computed with a GPU. My friend wrote an implementation that can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Snektron/40aa8be62db499148c588dee02a45e17). This can be run on CUDA compatible nvidia GPUs. Finding the factor took about 18 hours on a Nvidia GTX Titan X pascal.

Comment: Since I do not expect a prime divisor to be found until the end of this bounty, I reward the relatively large search limit with an accept and 100 reputation points.

Comment: @Peter divisor found!

Comment: Impressive @sophie!  The divisor is very low compared with the statistically based expectations (see big prime country's answer).  Do you have any idea why it happened?

Comment: The chance of finding a divisor up to 1590429889 is 17.3% aka about one sixth. I think if I tried to find a special meaning every time I got a stroke of luck equivalent to rolling 6 on a dice I'd go insane.

Comment: @Sophie $(1)$ Thank you for the search. My bounty was well invested :) $(2)$ Does this estimate consider that there cannot be a prime factor less than 11! ? $(3)$ 1:6 is not so low after all $(4)$ Apparently, your software is much much faster than pari/gp. $(5)$ Did you search by brute force (meaning that there is no smaller prime factor) ?

Comment: (2) yes it does, it's the $\log(a)/\log(b)$ from big prime country's answer (4) There are several factors to this: the fact that I'm using a compiled language, arbitrary precision integers are slower than fixed size ones. I got a big speedup after I noticed that $11!<2^{32}$, and of course parallelism. We were checking batches of 3072 primes 1150 per second. (5) yes.

Answer (score 29):

By Mertens' theorem, we have

$$\prod_{p < n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log(n)},$$

In particular, if you do "trial division" of a large number $N \gg b^2$ for $a < p < b$ with $a$ and $b$ very large, you
expect to fail to find a factor approximately

$$\prod_{a < p < b} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) \sim \frac{\log(a)}{\log(b)}$$

of the time. In your case, you have $a \sim 11!$.
So, for example, to have a 50% chance of finding a factor, you would want to take $\log(b) \sim 2 \log(a)$,
or $b \sim a^2$. For $b = 11!$, this would involve trial division to primes well over $10^{15}$, and in particular (estimating using the prime number theorem) more than 10 trillion primes. That seems a little unlikely to ever be possible.

Note that $11!$ is about $39$ million. If you wanted merely to check the next 10 million primes after $11!$ (involving taking $b$ around $230$ million or so), your chance of finding a factor would be less than 10%.

In particular, even if you speed up your computation of $(11!)! \pmod p$ for $p \sim 10^{10}$ to one second (on pari currently it seems to take around 13 seconds), it would then take 80 days to have a 10% chance of finding an answer.